# detect changes of a variable and raise event

Tags: angular, events

I have a 'Refresh Data ' button that activates this function :

```
  refreshBatchData(){

    this.homeService.refreshData().subscribe(data => {
      this.batchSpotData = data;   
    })


  }
```

and I want to raise an event when batchSpotData received the data and then activate another function :

```
getProblematicBatchData() {
    this.homeService.getProblematicBatchData().subscribe(bdata => {
      this.badDataFromBatchService = bdata;
      this.batchSource.data = this.badDataFromBatchService;

    })

  }
```

both functions are in the same component.
I tried to define 'batchSpotData' with @Input() property and then using ngOnChanges, and calling the second function from inside it, but with no success.
I am new to angular, so please exceuse me.

Would like to know what is the most efficient way to perform this action, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you not simply call `this.getProblematicBatchData()` inside the first subscribe? After you do `this.batchSpotData = data;`

Answer (score 1):

For handling async actions you can use [rxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/) functions. If `data` and `bdata` are both needed at the same time you can use [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) :

```
combineLatest(this.homeService.refreshData(), 
              this.homeService.getProblematicBatchData())
.subscribe(([data, bdata]) => {
   this.batchSpotData = data;
   this.badDataFromBatchService = bdata;
   this.batchSource.data = this.badDataFromBatchService;
})
```

Comment: I need 'getProblematicBatchData' after 'refreshBatchData' finishes, so doing what @bugs suggested would be a proper way ?

Comment: You could use `switchMap` like this :
this.homeService.refreshData()
.pipe(switchMap(data => {
 this.batchSpotData = data;
 return this.homeService.getProblematicBatchData();
})).subscribe(bdata => {
 this.badDataFromBatchService = bdata;
 this.batchSource.data = this.badDataFromBatchService;
});